# Unable to set Custom "Link URL" for Featured Image, and More?

Tags: post-thumbnails, urls, post-meta

I have an issue that I believe can be solved one of two ways.

I am using Featured Images in posts for content on a home page slider. What I would like to have happen is to have the destination links on click to be custom. Not the post or image URL of the post/featured image being used to feed the slider.

1) I thought I might be able to use the Image URL feature on the image itself, but it turns out the Featured Images will not accept a custom URL. It defaults back to the image path.

2) I have tried using a custom Post Meta field, but my attempts to retrieve that meta have been unsuccessful. I have set a Meta Field with the name "slider-url" and have dropped the path to the desired destination page into the field. I am then using the following code in the loop for the slider (from the WP Codex) in an attempt to pull that value into the href="" `<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "slider-url", true); ?>`

I am hoping someone might either have a hack for the Featured Image "Image URL" (along with a way to retrieve that URL), or alternately some insight into why my custom post meta might not be working.

Thanks in advance for your time and expertise.

Cheers!

EDIT:
Here's the specific block of code. It's contained within the PHP file of the slider plugin.

```
    <div id="slider">
<?php 
    $category = get_option('wpns_category');
    $n_slices = get_option('wpns_slices');
?>
<?php query_posts( 'cat='.$category.'&posts_per_page=$n_slices' ); if( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "slider-url", true); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"> 
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </a>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php endwhile; endif;?>
    <?php wp_reset_query();?>
</div>
```

Additionally, here's a screen capture of the post meta field: http://s.sct.io/Bl6O

Thanks again!

Comment: Can we have a look at the block of code you are currently using to get a better idea of what your trying to achieve.

Comment: @Ijaas -- I've edited my original post to include more info. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up the code u have given and it should work as you intend.

Let me know if your still having problems.

```
<div id="slider">
<?php
    $c = get_option('wpns_category');
    $n = get_option('wpns_slices');
    $s = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => $c, 'posts_per_page' => $n ) );
    if( $s->have_posts() ): while( $s->have_posts() ): $s->the_post(); global $post;
?>
        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){ ?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "slider-url", true); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </a>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php endwhile; endif;?>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Many kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your logic, however I assume you just want to display a post featured image into a slider locate in home page, in this cause, why don't try something simple like this:

- Create a category for the features images, lets called 'featured', then try this code in the home page:

  ```
  <?php query_posts('category_name=featured'); ?> 
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
  <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "slider-url", true); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"> 
  <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
  </a>
  <?php endif ?>
  <?php endwhile; endif;?>
  <?php wp_reset_query();?>
  ```

Let me know if it works ;)

Regards!